# Exit java process.exec when parent thead stops

Tags: java, multithreading, process

I have a java application which creates a thread which will call Process.exec to start a python program. However when I exit my program the java threads will stop, but my python process continues to run. Is there a way to stop the python process when I stop the execution of the java file?

Here is a snipit of the code which starts the new thread which will then start the execution of the python script.

```
MyRunnable myRun = new MyRunnable();
Thread myThread = new Thread(myRun);
myThread.start();
```

The myRunable.java class is as follows

```
public class myRunnable implements Runnable(){
    public myRunnable(){

    }
public void run(){
    try{
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = rt.exec("python myPythonScript.py");
        StreamGobbler errGobber = new StreamGobbler(proc.getErrorStream(), "Error");
        StreamGobbler outputGobbler = new StreamGobbler(proc.getInputStream(), "Output");
        errgobbler.start()
        outpoutGobbler.start()
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
}
```

When I exit my java application, the threads stop running, however my python script will continue to execute in a separate process. I want to stop this process when the threads exit.

EDIT: 
I started to play around with Runtime.addShutdownHOok() as mentioned below. I'm still testing it to make sure it works how I would expect but so far it seems to be working. I edited my Runnable class to include a shutdownHook as follows:

```
public void run(){
    try{
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        final Process proc = rt.exec("python myPythonScript.py");
        rt.addShutdownHOok(new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                System.out.println("Exit process");
                proc.destroy();
            }
        )};
        StreamGobbler errGobber = new StreamGobbler(proc.getErrorStream(), "Error");
        StreamGobbler outputGobbler = new StreamGobbler(proc.getInputStream(), "Output");
        errgobbler.start()
        outpoutGobbler.start()
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Runtime.exec()` returns a `Process` object. You can use that to kill the external application:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
p.destory();
```

Comment: What would be the best way to call process.destroy() whenever the java application is closed or stopped for any reason?

Comment: Check out `Runtime.addShutdownHook()`. You can register code to be executed before the JVM exists.

Comment: Thanks, Ill give it a look and see where it gets me.